# In Bitcoin QT 0.12 for Windows, how do you whitelist an IP address?

Tags: command-line-options

I believe the answer is that you enter the command line option whitebind for IPV4 or whitelist for IPV6.

When I tried it, I first got a message that I needed to include the port, so I included the port, but then I got an error message saying "Unable to bind to {IP.Add.re.ss:Port} on this computer (bind returned the error The requested address is not valid in its context. (10049))."

I did a search for whitelisting multiple IP addresses and didn't find any results, but through experimentation, I determined that repeating the command line option multiple times works, at least to get the errors I describe above.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 options (either command line or in the bitcoind.conf file) that have to do with whitelisting. I myself have only used whitelist where you simply specify the IP address (IPv4), without port number.

-whitelist=192.168.10.20

According to the documentation you can also specify a netmask, which I haven't used yet, but should be in this format if I'm not mistaken:

-whitelist=192.168.10.0/24

> **-whitebind**=
>          Bind to given address and whitelist peers connecting to it. Use
>          [host]:port notation for IPv6
>
> **-whitelist**=
>          Whitelist peers connecting from the given netmask or IP address. Can be
>          specified multiple times. Whitelisted peers cannot be DoS banned and
>          their transactions are always relayed, even if they are already in the
>          mempool, useful e.g. for a gateway
>
> **-whitelistrelay**
>          Accept relayed transactions received from whitelisted peers even when
>          not relaying transactions (default: 1)
>
> **-whitelistforcerelay**
>          Force relay of transactions from whitelisted peers even they violate
>          local relay policy (default: 1)